# How to create an instance of the same type in a baseclass in typescript

Tags: inheritance, typescript, types

If B extends A, can A define a method that creates a new B?

```
class SetA {
   constructor(public items:any[]) {
   }
   createNew(items){
      return new *typeof this*(items); //<-- insert actually working magic here
   }
   clone(){
      return this.createNew(this.items);
   }
}
class SetB extends SetA { }

var x = new SetB([1,2,3]);
x.clone(); //<-- returns a new SetB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
type SetConstructor<T extends SetA> = {
    new (items:any[]): T;
}

class SetA {
   constructor(public items:any[]) {}

   createNew(items): this {
      return new (this.constructor as SetConstructor<this>)(items);
   }

   clone(){
      return this.createNew(this.items);
   }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20SetConstructor%3CT%20extends%20SetA%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new%20(items%3Aany%5B%5D)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SetA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20constructor(public%20items%3Aany%5B%5D)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20createNew(items)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20(this.constructor%20as%20SetConstructor%3Cthis%3E)(items)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20clone()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.createNew(this.items)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SetB%20extends%20SetA%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20new%20SetB(%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D)%3B%0D%0Ax.clone()%3B%20%2F%2F%3C--%20returns%20a%20new%20SetB))

The return type of the `createNew` method is `this` which is the [Polymorphic this types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types).

Comment: Great! Works perfectly!